# Oracle pagination query and user defined function - slow execution

Tags: oracle, performance, pagination, user-defined-functions, oracle12c

My query is like this:

```
   select id, fn_calc(col)
   from table_a
   order by id
   offset 1483800 rows fetch next 100 rows only;
```

Note that the paging offset is extremely high - `table_a` has about 1,500,000 rows.

The above query takes very long, but when `fn_calc(col)` is replaced by `col`, query speed is satisfactory - at least 5 times faster. But when the offset is 0 or 100, two queries are almost equally fast. Why this difference?

Possible reasons I can think of:

- Oracle executes `fn_calc()` 1483900 times, although it is logically not neccessary. (It is enough to call it only 100 times)
- The calling cost for a user function in a query is very high.

I'm using Oracle 12c on ExaData.

Any suggestion can help.

**UPDATE:**

When the above query is changed as follows:

```
   select id, fn_calc(col)
   from
   (
     select id, col
     from table_a
     order by id
     offset 1483800 rows fetch next 100 rows only
   )
   order by id
```

The query speed is comparable to the case when fn_calc() is not called at all.

Why this?

**UPDATE:**

The execution plans are as follows: (Sorry, currently only I have is SQLDevelper, so I had to capture the result.)

The first query:

[image: First query]

The second query (which uses subquery):

[image: Second query (with subquery)]

**To down-voters and close-voters:** Please specify your concerns about this question before you vote. I'll update my question accordingly. This question is about the real and serious problem to me. Please do not deprive the chance to get help.

Comment: Check execution plans for both. Probably index usage. Second you need to call function for each row, it takes time too.

Comment: How many distinct col values are there? is the function deterministic? Also you didn't define any ORDER BY which makes the OFFSET effectively unimportant

Comment: @lad2025 The execution plans are the same.

Comment: Have you tried creating a function based index on fn_calc(col)?

Comment: @Husqvik I've added deterministic keyword to the function, but the result was the same. The number of distinct values are about 525,000.

Comment: @YaronIdan No, but in fact, in a real query, the column is not so important to have a function index. In a real query, the column is one of many columns on the select clause.

Comment: @zeodtr, just checked with that high number of distinct values the deterministic and scalar subquery caching will be not much efficient. You should ad DETERMINISTIC only if the function is deterministic.

Comment: @Husqvik The function is actually deterministic. It just checks the string format of the column value. (BTW I don't want to check it on the query time - it should be done on the insertion time. But currently I'm stuck.)

Comment: @zeodtr What is the purpose of the pagination query when you haven't used an **ORDER BY**?

Comment: @LalitKumarB Sorry, I simplified the query too much. In the real query of course there was a order by clause. I've edited the question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, what is the purpose of the **pagination query** when you are not using **ORDER BY** clause. You are **randomly fetching the rows**, i.e. Oracle will internally apply **ORDER BY NULL**.

Secondly, since you have the function in the SELECT and not in the filter predicate, the explain plan should be same. The only extra time spent should be due to the function.

For example,

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_char(
  2      i_empno NUMBER)
  3    RETURN VARCHAR2
  4  AS
  5    v_empno VARCHAR2(10);
  6  BEGIN
  7    v_empno := TO_CHAR(i_empno);
  8    return v_empno;
  9  END;
 10  /

Function created.
```

Let's compare the **explain plan**:

```
SQL> set autot on explain
SQL>
SQL> SELECT f_char(empno) FROM emp
  2  OFFSET 5 ROWS
  3  FETCH NEXT 5 rows only;

F_CHAR(EMPNO)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
7698
7782
7788
7839
7844


Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 3611411408

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation              | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT       |      |    14 | 28210 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  VIEW                  |      |    14 | 28210 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  2 |   WINDOW NOSORT STOPKEY|      |    14 |    56 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   3 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL   | EMP  |    14 |    56 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter("from$_subquery$_002"."rowlimit_$$_rownumber"<=CASE  WHEN
              (5>=0) THEN 5 ELSE 0 END +5 AND "from$_subquery$_002"."rowlimit_$$
_rownu

              mber">5)
   2 - filter(ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY  NULL )<=CASE  WHEN (5>=0)
              THEN 5 ELSE 0 END +5)


SQL> SELECT empno FROM emp
  2  OFFSET 5 ROWS
  3  FETCH NEXT 5 rows only;

     EMPNO
----------
      7698
      7782
      7788
      7839
      7844


Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 3611411408

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation              | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT       |      |    14 |   364 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  VIEW                  |      |    14 |   364 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  2 |   WINDOW NOSORT STOPKEY|      |    14 |    56 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   3 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL   | EMP  |    14 |    56 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter("from$_subquery$_002"."rowlimit_$$_rownumber"<=CASE  WHEN
              (5>=0) THEN 5 ELSE 0 END +5 AND "from$_subquery$_002"."rowlimit_$$
_rownu

              mber">5)
   2 - filter(ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY  NULL )<=CASE  WHEN (5>=0)
              THEN 5 ELSE 0 END +5)
```

Comment: Sorry, I simplified the query too much. In the real query of course there was a order by clause. I've edited the question accordingly.

Comment: The problem is that the additional cost caused by the function is unreasonably high. I suspect that other cause that's related to the Oracle's handling of the user-defined function on the pagination query may exist.

Comment: @zeodtr Yes, saw  your update. Can you post the explain plan the way I have shown in `SQL*Plus`. Copy paste the entire session from `SQL*Plus`, use the `set autot on explain` as I did. Also, make sure you do `set time on timing on` first. Do this for both the queries.

Comment: I've updated the question with the execution plans. Sorry that it's the screen capture of SQLDeveloper which is the only one I have currently.

Comment: @zeodtr Well, that's not going to help because the important columns of the explain plan are missing. Let me help you with generating explain plan in readable text format. See my blog here http://lalitkumarb.com/2014/05/31/oracle-explain-plan/ You can run those in SQL Developer as script(F5) and then copy paste the output. Sounds good?

Comment: Thanks, but since it's late here, I'll return tomorrow.

Comment: No problem, make sure you also post the function code.